# Overiding global command in unix

Tags: unix, path

I am using a server, and I don't have root access. I need a newer version of a package. So, I installed it with the prefix to my local directory and updated $PATH and $LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
Since the server has the same command, when I use `which` command it stills points to the old version. How can I override that command with my new command in my local directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating $PATH is correct; however, since it is interpreted left-to-right, your custom `bin` directory must come *before* the system directories:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

...or similar.